# Manipulating API in Vue methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a method that is making 2 API calls simultaneously. How can I take the results of the API calls and manipulate them in another method within the same Vue component.

```
 buildChart(){
    *method where calls would be manipulated"

}
     async updateChart() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        const apiCall1 = await get().then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
        const apiCall2= await get().then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` to execute the two requests in parallel, the result will be an array of two items of each async request.

```js
async buildChart(){
  // here result will be an array with two items of the result of each async get method.
  const [firstRequest, secondRequest] = await updateChart()
  this.isLoading = false;
},
updateChart() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  return Promise.all([get(), get()])
}
```